# Case Insensitive map in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, case-insensitive, linkedhashmap

I have a code that writes to a text file and then prints out how many times each word in the text file is found. It works fine, but it needs to be case insensitive. And I'm stuck. May you can suggest how can it be done?

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String w : data) {
        Integer n = map.get(w.);
        n = (n == null) ? 1 : ++n;
        map.put(w, n);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Here's the code.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just lower or uppercase the text before putting the data into the map...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the strings into lower case while putting into the map.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (String w : data) {
    Integer n = map.get(w.toLowerCase());
    n = (n == null) ? 1 : ++n;
    map.put(w.toLowerCase(), n);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Almost. You also have to use lowercase when you get the counter from the map. :)

Comment: Or just `map.merge(w.toLowerCase(), 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, you need to lowercase (or uppercase) the keys before putting entries into the map. For counting words, you can use [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.forEach(w -> frequencies.merge(w.toLowerCase(), 1, Integer::sum);
```

Alternately, you could do it with streams:

```
Map<String, Long> frequencies = data.stream()
    collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            String::toLowerCase,
            Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 3):

just use `.toLowerCase()` for `w` inside your `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CaseInsensitiveMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html) from Apache Commons Collections.

Others have suggested changing the keys to lowercase but ***this may not be an option*** since other parts of the program could also have access to the map and expect the keys to be in their original format. So you need to tread carefully depending on the use case.

Comment: According to the documentation, you have linked, this map implementation works exactly like the other solutions, i.e. will convert all keys to lowercase too.